# How to put condition for loops which is splited by delimeters?

Tags: java

```
   1 condition:

    String str = "2d5";
    String[] temp;
    String delimiter = "d";
    temp = str.split(delimiter);
    String a=temp[0];
    String b=temp[1];
    Integer q,w,e;
    q=Integer.parseInt(a);
    w=Integer.parseInt(b);
    e=q*w;
    for(int i =q; i <=e ; i++){ //values will be (2,3.4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    data.add(new Card(i));} //data is an arraylist and Card is a class, here values will be stored in an arraylist)

       2nd Condition:

       str = ""2d5-2;
       delimiter = "d|\\-";
       temp = str.split(delimiter);
       String a=temp[0];
       String b=temp[1];
       String c=temp[2];
       q=Integer.parseInt(a);
       w=Integer.parseInt(b);
       r=Integer.parseInt(c);
       for(int i =0; i < r ; i++){ 
       data1.add(data.get(0)); // data1 is another arraylist 
       data.remove(0); // values will be removed from arraylist stating from index 0 i.e (4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

         }
```

Here I actually wanted to do is that whenever I split string by "d" delimiter i wanted the 1st condition to run, also when I split string by "-" delimiter i wanted the 2nd condition to run in the same Class.

Comment: Your for loop condition is totally different then why you need two condition?? clearly say what is required/final o/p??

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for something like:

```
String [] temp = str.split("-");
if (temp.length == 1) // That is, "2d5" format
{
    delimiter = "d";
    temp = str.split(delimiter);
    doCondition1(...);
}
else
{
    delimiter = "d|\\-";
    temp = str.split(delimiter);
    doCondition2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (delimiter.equals("d")) {
        //delimiter is 'd'. So carry out 1st condition action.
    } else if (delimiter.equals("-")) {
        //delimiter is '-'. So carry out 2nd condition action.  
    }
```